# Mistake on ESTA application

Tags: usa, esta, id

I made my ESTA application to visit the USA, in a few weeks.

Although my application has been approved, I saw later a mistake at the NIN (National Identification Number). That is my country ID (Europe).

Is there a problem with that? All the other info seems to be correct and the passport of course. Do I need to pay again for a new ESTA, for this -non important?- mistake, although I already got approved to travel?

I tried to contact the relevant office, but they were not very helpful. I only got one copy/paste reply.

Thanks.

Comment: What did the reply say?

Comment: They replied a general copy/paste text, like this: ** When you have to apply for a new ESTA: 
An ESTA application must contain correct pertinent biographical data.  This includes full name, date of birth, citizenship, place of birth, gender, and passport information. If you are or have ever been a citizen of another country, this must be included on your ESTA application.

If you have made an error in your parents’ biographical information, you will need to submit an updated ESTA application. __ I got a large email, but they didn't answer my NIN problem.

Comment: Their reply states "_An ESTA application must contain correct pertinent biographical data_" and your question is asking whether it matters if you've included incorrect data...

Comment: I made the same mistake. did everything go well with you? Thank you